# React - If condition outside an html tag attribute

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I know that a condition inside an attribute works fine, but this gives a string of false in the **data-tip** attribute when active is false.

```
<div data-tip={active && 'hello'}>

...
</div>
```

I want the data-tip attribute to not be shown in the rendered component when active is false `<div> ... </div>`.
If think I can do that if I add a condition outside the data-tip attribute, but it is failing.

```
<div {active && data-tip='hello'}>

...
</div>
```

How can I achieve this without putting the condition outside the div element?

Comment: Have you tried `<div {active ? {'data-tip': 'hello'} : {}}>`?

Comment: That works @PrathapReddy, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass undefined it will not be rendered.

```
<div data-tip={!active ? undefined : 'hello'}>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with the `spread` operator,

```js
    let dataTipProps = {
       id:'foo'
    };

    let active = true;

    if(active)
       dataTipProps['data-tip'] ='hello';
```

Render with spread, optionally passing other props also.

```
    <div {...dataTipProps}>
    
    ...
    </div>
```

It will be appearing in HTML as

```html
    <div id='foo' data-tip='hello'> //if active
    <div id='foo'> //if !active
```